# Airflow unable to import the airflow.providers

Tags: python, airflow

Im wants to import Airflow Google providers. So I installed it.

```
pip3 install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

Im able to see all the hooks and everything under the packages directory.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfer
```

But when I run the import command its failing.

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sql_to_gcs import BaseSQLToGCSOperator


Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from custom.custom_PostgresToGCSOperator import custom_PostgresToGCSOperator
  File "/root/airflow/dags/custom/custom_PostgresToGCSOperator.py", line 8, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sql_to_gcs import BaseSQLToGCSOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when upgrading to 2.0.0a1, what I did:

- install providers package
- Download the upgrade version:

  - wget
    https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/airflow/2.0.0a1/apache-airflow-2.0.0a1-bin.tar.gz
- pip install apache-airflow-2.0.0a1-bin.tar.gz
- airflow db upgrade
- airflow scheduler -D; airflow webserver -D

Also refer to this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-8+Split+Providers+into+Separate+Packages+for+Airflow+2.0